# Can't create a table in SQL

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Can't create a table in Cloud SQL.
Error : Table "Persons" must be qualified with a dataset (e.g. dataset.table).

I have tried different names and still can't create tables.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images for text information.  Just edit the post and copy paste the sql.

Comment: FYI - see [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for many reasons why it's important to post properly formatted text and not images of text.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are missing the dataset name on where the table will be created. Something like this `CREATE TABLE <myDatasetName>.Persons(...)` .

For your reference please visit this documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#create_an_empty_table_with_a_schema_definition), Additionally you can visit [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#create-dataset) for creating a dataset.